# Tensorflow Dataset.from_tensor_slices taking too long

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have the following code:

```
data = np.load("data.npy")
print(data) # Makes sure the array gets loaded in memory
dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data))
```

The file `"data.npy"` is 3.3 GB. Reading the file with numpy takes a couple of seconds but then the next line that creates the tensorflow dataset object takes ages to execute. Why is that? What is it doing under the hood?

Answer (score 6):

Quoting this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34119852/4727666):

> [`np.load`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) of a `npz` just returns a file loader, not the actual data. It's a 'lazy loader', loading the particular array only when accessed.

That is why it is fast.

**Edit 1:** to expand a bit more this answer, another quote from [tensorflow's documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#consuming_numpy_arrays):

> If all of your input data fit in memory, the simplest way to create a `Dataset` from them is to convert them to `tf.Tensor` objects and use `Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`.
>
> This works well for a small dataset, but wastes memory---because the contents of the array will be copied multiple times---and can run into the 2GB limit for the tf.GraphDef protocol buffer.

The link also shows how to do it a efficiently.

Comment: If I try to print the `data`, so that I make sure it actually gets loaded, it still takes a couple of seconds, while the `Dataset` takes minutes.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily print all the data.  Printing it or not does not ensure that it "actually gets loaded".  I'm not an expert at tensorflow but just looking at the code it looks like `from_tensor_slices` loops over the entire data set (and in a rather slow manner too) which definitely *will* load all the data.  IMO this can probably be sped up but in fairness I haven't tried.  At a certain point you might just have to throw more hardware at it if your machine is choking on 3.3GB in memory.

Comment: Does this mean that if you do `tf.data.Dataset.fron_tensor_slices(filenames)` where `filenames` is a large set of files, it will try to load them all up-front instead of lazy-loading them during training?

Comment: Did you get an answer to this? I also have the same question as above.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data = np.load("data.npy")
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(a)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=1000)
dataset = dataset.batch(128)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_batch = iterator.get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={a: data})
```

When processing large dataset, `tf.placeholder` is better.