# Modify only a few bytes from a npz numpy file without rewriting the whole file

Tags: python, numpy, serialization, npz-file

This works to write and load a numpy array + metadata in a `.npz` compressed file (here the compression is useless because it's random, but anyway):

```
import numpy as np

# save
D = {"x": np.random.random((10000, 1000)), "metadata": {"date": "20221123", "user": "bob", "name": "abc"}}
with open("test.npz", "wb") as f:
    np.savez_compressed(f, **D)

# load
D2 = np.load("test.npz", allow_pickle=True)
print(D2["x"])
print(D2["metadata"].item()["date"])
```

Let's say we want to change only a metadata:

```
D["metadata"]["name"] = "xyz"
```

**Is there a way to re-write to disk in `test.npz` only `D["metadata"]` and not the whole file because `D["x"]` has not changed?**

In my case, the .npz file can be 100 MB to 4 GB large, that's why it would be interesting to rewrite only the metadata.

Comment: It should be possible. That npz file would be an archive with two files inside: `x.npy` and `metadata.npy`. With python's `zipfile` builtin, maybe we can open the archive's specific subfile and modify it somehow.

Comment: Interesting solution @Mercury. Do you think there is high-level API to do this, or should we do this manually with `zipfile`?

Comment: The problem you have is very intuitive and `np.savez` and `np.load` do extensively use `zipfile` already, so ideally we *shouldn't* need the lower level library. In fact, the object you have after loading, `D2`, is an `NpzFile` object. While there is no direct page on this on the numpy docs, I can see from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119752/querying-a-numpy-array-of-numpy-arrays-saved-as-an-npz-is-slow/34119852#34119852) + `help(NpzFile)` that `np.load` is lazy and doesn't actually load everything in memory. This makes a high level solution possible; let me run a few checks.

Comment: Do a simple `np.save('metadata.npy', {"date": "20221123", "user": "bob", "name": "abc"}, allow_pickle=True)`, and then try to open that file with your favorite text editor.  You'll see that finding the 'abc' string is not trivial, much less changing it to 'xyz'.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately the solution that I could get to work (thus far) is the one I originally thought of with `zipfile`.

```
import zipfile
import os
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def archive_manager(archive_name: str, key: str):
    f, s = zipfile.ZipFile(archive_name, "a"), f"{key}.npy"

    yield s

    f.write(s)
    f.close()
    os.remove(s)
```

Let's say we want to change `metadata`:

```
new_metadata = {"date": "20221123", "user": "bob", "name": "xyz"}

with archive_manager("test.npz", "metadata") as archive:
    np.save(archive, new_metadata)
```

---

`np.load` returns an `NpzFile`, which is a lazy loader. However, `NpzFile` objects aren't directly writeable. We cannot also do something like `D["metadata"] = new_metadata` until `D` has been converted to a dict, and that loses the lazy functionality.

Comment: Thanks @Mercury. Just to be sure, why is there a `os.remove(...)`? Does it involve creating and deleting a temp file? If so, could we use `io.bytesIO` or `io.StringIO` or https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html?

Comment: PS: Isn't there a method in zipfile to edit an existing file inside a zip?

Comment: If you open a file in `append` mode, you can write new values to it, and even overwrite existing bytes if you use `seek`.  But an `.npy` file is binary (not text).  As your use of `allow_pickle` and `item` show, your `metadata` `dict`  has been "pickled" (converted to a binary string), and saved as an element of an object dtype array.  That's way too many layers to go through to "edit in-place".  Mercury's idea of writing a new `npy` file to the archive is the best we can do.